# How can I add this float[] vertexData to a Vector3f list?

Tags: java, arrays, lwjgl

How I can add vertex data (`float[]`) to a `Vector3f` list? It gives me an error if I try.

```
float[] vertexData = new float[ allindices2.length * vertexDataSize / 3];
for (int i = 0; i < vertexData.length / vertexDataSize; i++){
      vertexData[i * vertexDataSize + 0] = Float.parseFloat(allindices2 [Integer.parseInt(allindices2 [i * source.size() + 0]) * 3 + 0]);
      vertexData[i * vertexDataSize + 1] = Float.parseFloat(allpositions2[Integer.parseInt(allindices2[i * source.size() + 0]) * 3 + 1]);
      vertexData[i * vertexDataSize + 2] = Float.parseFloat(allpositions2[Integer.parseInt(allindices2[i * source.size() + 0]) * 3 + 2]);

      vertices.add(vertexData);
}
```

Comment: You cant (directly). A Vector3f isn't the same data type as a float array. Also, how does your issue relate to XML or Collada?

Comment: My bad for putting xml and collada(apologizes), but if you can't do it directly then how can you do it? I'm trying to look for a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the `vertexData` array for any other reason, you should not create it at all. Instead, you can directly create the required `Vector3f` instances.

```
for (int i = 0; i < vertexData.length / vertexDataSize; i++){

      float x = Float.parseFloat(allindices2  [Integer.parseInt(allindices2[i * source.size() + 0]) * 3 + 0]);
      float y = Float.parseFloat(allpositions2[Integer.parseInt(allindices2[i * source.size() + 0]) * 3 + 1]);
      float z = Float.parseFloat(allpositions2[Integer.parseInt(allindices2[i * source.size() + 0]) * 3 + 2]);

      vertices.add(new Vector3f(x,y,z));
}
```

Nevertheless, all these `parse...` calls and the general structure look **highly** dubious. Unless you obtain this data directly from a file or so, you should consider a different data model.

Additionally:

- Are you sure that the first `allindices2` should not be `allpositions2`?
- There's no need to do work twice. You can pull out the computation of the index.

Most likely, the code could also be written as

```
for (int i = 0; i < vertexData.length / vertexDataSize; i++){
      int index = Integer.parseInt(allindices2[i * source.size()]);
      float x = Float.parseFloat(allpositions2[index * 3 + 0]);
      float y = Float.parseFloat(allpositions2[index * 3 + 1]);
      float z = Float.parseFloat(allpositions2[index * 3 + 2]);
      vertices.add(new Vector3f(x,y,z));
}
```